# UIBezierPath Creating Triangle,Square,Circle Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, geometry, uibezierpath

I am attempting to create three shapes: a Circle, Square & Triangle. I have created the circle & square, but am unable to create the triangle. My biggest issue is to keep all three shapes in the center of the screen. The circle and square are fine, but when I attempt to make the triangle it does not work. I am also trying to make the triangle look like a "play button" so that the "tip" of the triangle is facing to the right. Here is the code.

```
func trainglePathWithCenter(center: CGPoint, side: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath()

    let startX = center.x - side / 2
    let startY = center.y - side / 2

   path.move(to: CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY - side))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: startX + side, y: startY + side/2))
    path.close()

    return path
}


func circlePathWithCenter(center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath()
    circlePath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: -CGFloat(M_PI), endAngle: -CGFloat(M_PI/2), clockwise: true)
    circlePath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: -CGFloat(M_PI/2), endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
    circlePath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI/2), clockwise: true)
    circlePath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI/2), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), clockwise: true)
    circlePath.close()
    return circlePath
}

func squarePathWithCenter(center: CGPoint, side: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
    let squarePath = UIBezierPath()
    let startX = center.x - side / 2
    let startY = center.y - side / 2

    squarePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY))

    squarePath.addLine(to: squarePath.currentPoint)
    squarePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: startX + side, y: startY))
    squarePath.addLine(to: squarePath.currentPoint)
    squarePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: startX + side, y: startY + side))
    squarePath.addLine(to: squarePath.currentPoint)
    squarePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY + side))
    squarePath.addLine(to: squarePath.currentPoint)
    squarePath.close()
    return squarePath

}
```

Where am I going wrong with the geometry for the triangle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You subtracted when you need to add.  Remember, `+Y` is down.

Change:

```
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY - side))
```

To:

```
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY + side))
```

---

Here it is running in a Playground:

[image: Triangle demo running in a Playground]

---

Here's the full code for the Playground demo:

```
class Custom: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let path = trainglePathWithCenter(center: self.center, side: self.bounds.width / 2)

        path.stroke()
    }

    func trainglePathWithCenter(center: CGPoint, side: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        let startX = center.x - side / 2
        let startY = center.y - side / 2

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY + side))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: startX + side, y: startY + side/2))
        path.close()

        return path
    }
}

let custom = Custom(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
custom.backgroundColor = .white
```

Answer (score 2):

[Result triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhnUD.png)

Code in swift5

```
//TriangleView

extension UIView {

    func setRightTriangle(targetView:UIView?){
        let heightWidth = targetView!.frame.size.width //you can use triangleView.frame.size.height
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: heightWidth/2, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth, y: heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y:heightWidth))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y:0))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        targetView!.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
    }

    func setLeftTriangle(targetView:UIView?){
        let heightWidth = targetView!.frame.size.width
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: heightWidth/2, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y: heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y:heightWidth))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y:0))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        targetView!.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
    }

    func setUpTriangle(targetView:UIView?){
     let heightWidth = targetView!.frame.size.width
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: heightWidth))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y: heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth, y:heightWidth))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:heightWidth))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        targetView!.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
    }

    func setDownTriangle(targetView:UIView?){
        let heightWidth = targetView!.frame.size.width
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth/2, y: heightWidth/2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:heightWidth, y:0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))

        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        targetView!.layer.insertSublayer(shape, at: 0)
    }
}
```